# jquery-ui tooltip() function doesn't get recognized

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm getting the following errors when trying to use jquery-ui tooltip() in my php page.

```
15:10:28.470 TypeError: t(...).on is not a function 1 jquery-ui.min.js:6:21131
17:30:03.550 TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function 1 fx-analisys.php:50:6
```

my php page:

```
<html>
<?php var $content = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                         $(document).ready(function(){
                             loadNe(\"MSAN-MCD\");
                         });
                      </script>"
?>

<head>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function loadNe(ne){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/NOKIA/fx-load.php?label=" + ne,
            async: true,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data){
                var content = fillResult(data);
                $(".sfp").tooltip();
            }
        });
     }
</script>
</head>

<body>
     <?php echo $content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The function fillResult(data) is just a function that fills the var content with the html content which will be shown in the page. This page contains a tag with "sfp" class which I want to see a tooltip on it.

What am I doing wrong? I just can't figure out

Comment: Before anyone asks, the jquery-ui.min.js is in the latest version

Answer (score 0):

try adding the bootstrap library and css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it upgrading all the jquery and jquery-ui files to the latest versions and inserting bootstrap.js and tether.js to make the tooltip() work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js-ui/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tether/dist/js/tether.min.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```